# Stable php api framework/CMF/CMS

Tags: api, frameworks, content-management-system, stability

I'm searching for a php API that will not change much and that will be supported a *long time*. I will use a framework or CMS depending on the case of my future works, so it's nice to have both.

Here's what I got from my research:

Framework:

- Codeigniter 2 --> stable, but everyone is questioning the future of it and miss a modular approach(hard to find up-to-date code).
- Symfony 2 --> a bit slower, but seems nice overall.

CMF/CMS:

- Wordpress --> seems like it's one of the most stable API in this category.

is there any other framework/CMS that I could consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 2 is one of the best options for a php framework (my opinion and also other big goys opinion), but when it came out from symfony 1.4 it seems like a total different framework, so you can have a pretty good option with this framework if you still on version 2, but if you want to upgrade in the future could be hard, or may be they won't change a lot like they did from 1.4 to 2.0, but it's a chance.

Codeigniter is stable but I only found it suitable for small projects, because when you already have worked with symfony or other frameworks, you find out that codeigniter let you have a messy file structure, specially with many developers working at the same time. Symfony helps you to have all more organized.

Wordpress is really standar in the market but for bloggin, if you have integration to do, watch out because wordpress changes their api from version to version, so I would take care, I prefer a framework if I have integration, because wordpress updates are many year to year and may be you'll need to update your code from time to time.

My final recomendation is **Symfony**, because is the big guy on the block, there are a lot of documentation, a lot of exmaples, more community every day, and make your code be more structured so you don't have to look for many others only if you are looking for a concrete caracteristic, but I doubt symfony can't do anything you could want.

Comment: I have heard that wordpress was not breaking their API so much.. Oh well, it's good to know! Thank's for your answer, I will definitely try Symfony